# Find functions $f(x)$, so that $f(f(x)) = 4x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f$ is a function defined from real numbers to real numbers. There are three things that we know:

$f(x)$ is differentiable at all points,

$f(0) = 0$,

$f(f(x)) = 4x$.

What are the possible values of $f(x)$?

There are two not-hard-to-find solutions for $f(x)$ which satisfy the given equations, which are:

$f(x) = 2x$,

and

$f(x) = -2x$.

Are there (or, is it possible to find) any other functions which satisfy the given conditions? If so, how? If not, why?

edit:
I think that f is one-to-one, since if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then

$f(f(x_1)) = f(f(x_2))$, and

$4x_1 = 4x_2$

So, we can show that if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$.
Unfortunately, I couldn't go any further from this point. I don't even know if there is an answer to this question. I'm just open to any ideas from knowledgable people who can see more.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130259/if-ffx-4x-can-we-conclude-fx-pm2x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This argument works if $f'$ is continuous. Differentiating both sides of $f(f(x))=4x$ yields $f'(f(x))f'(x)=4$. Employing this with $f(x)$ in place of $x$ and using the condition gives $f'(4x)f'(f(x))=4$. Multiplying both sides by $f'(x)$ and using $f'(f(x))f'(x)=4$ gives $f'(4x)4 = 4f'(x)$, i.e., $f'(4x)=f'(x)$. It follows that $f'(x) = f'\left( {\frac{x}{{4^n }}} \right)$ for all $n\geq 1$. If $f'(x)$ is continuous, this implies $f'(x)=f'(0)$ for all $x$, i.e., $f'(x)$ is a constant function, i.e., $f(x)$ is a linear function. Since $f(0)=0$, $f$ must be of the form $ax$. Since $f(f(x))=4x$, we see that $a=\pm 2$ are the only possibilities.

Comment: $x=f(x)..?$ how does that work

Comment: Thx Brian @BrianMoehring (P.s: I too am a Brian :D, my stack name is a bad misspelling of my realname)

Comment: @Buraian Thanks for the comment, I rephrased it.

Answer (score 5):

**Hints:**

- Show that $f(x) $ is onto.

> For $ r \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(f(r/4)) = r $.

- Show that $f(x)$ is one-to-one.

> If $f(a) = f(b)$ then $f(f(a)) = f(f(b)) \Rightarrow 4a = 4b \Rightarrow a=b$.

- Hence an inverse exists. $ f^{-1} (x)$ is well defined.
- Show that $f(0) = 0$. (This doesn't need to be an assumption).
- Fix an $X \neq 0 $. Show that $f(X) \neq 0$.
- Define $ X_n$ to be the value of $ f^{(n) } (X) $ for all integers $ n$ (including negative $n$). Show that this is well defined. (Use the previous step)
- Show that $X_{2n} = 4^n X$, $X_{2n+1} = 4^n f(X)$ for all integers $n$, including negatives.
- Using differentiability at $0$, what can we conclude? Specifically, write $f'(0)$ in 2 ways.

> $f'(0) = \lim_{ n \rightarrow - \infty} \frac{ f(X_{2n} ) - f(0) } { X_{2n} - 0 } = \frac{ 4^k f(X) } { 4^k X } = \frac{f(X)}{X} $.

> $f'(0) = \lim_{n \rightarrow -\infty } \frac{ f(X_{2n+1} ) - f(0) } { X_{2n+ 1 } - 0 } = \frac{ 4^{k+1} X } { 4^k f(X) } = \frac{ 4 X } {f(X) }$.

Note: We used $ f(X) \neq 0$ here.

- Equating the 2 previous expressions gives us $f(X) = 2X$ or $f(X) = - 2X$. (We only know the value at this $X$, and not for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as yet.)
- Show that if there exists a $X$ such that $f(X) = 2X $, and a $Y$ such that $f(Y) = -2Y$, then $f'(0)$ is undefined.  Hence, the only solutions are $ f(x) = 2x \, \forall x$ and $ f(x) = -2x \, \forall x$.

  - Alternatively, show that if there exists a $X$ such that $f(X) = 2 $ (resp -2), then $f'(0) = 2 $ (resp -2) and hence $f(x) = 2x \, \forall x$ (resp -2x).

---

Note:

- Continuity is not sufficient. Find another solution where the function is continuous everywhere.
- Simply having continuity only at 0 isn't sufficient, as there is the solution $f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x \quad x \in \mathbb{Q}  \\ -2x \quad x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$.
- We could solve the recurrence for $X_n$ giving $X_n = \frac{ 2X + f(X) } { 4} 2^n + \frac{ 2X - f(X) } { 4} (-2)^n$, which simplifies to the solution above. This explicit form isn't used.

Comment: @pnguib What does it mean to be onto? What have you tried in that regards, and were are you stuck? Write that out in the question, so that others can see your work.

Comment: How do you achieve the second bullet for odd $n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've fleshed out the solution. We didn't actually need to solve the recurrence, we just needed $X_{n+2} = 4 X_n$.

Comment: The recurrence only holds for even $n$. How do you obtain information for odd $n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you mean? It holds for all $n$. EG We do have $fff(x) = 4f(x)$.

Comment: The identically zero function also is a solution. How is it missing?

Comment: @LawrenceMano That is not a solution. EG If $ f(1) = 0 $, then $ 0 = f(f(1)) = 4$.

Comment: Given that $f(x)$ is unknown, you don't have $X_1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $X_1 = f(X)$. Sure, we don't know what the exact value is right from the start, so we let it be a variable and then we solve for it subsequently. What is it that you're struggling with?

Comment: Of course. I don't see precisely where you establish that.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you not see me establish? The definition of $X_n$? The calculation that $f(X) = \pm 2X$? I'm having difficulty understanding you.

Comment: @CalvinLin oh yes thank you